# Connecting from Domain PC to non-domain PC

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, domain

I have a PC (windows 10) on my home network (non-domain), named Heathen.
I also have my work computer (Windows 10) on a domain network (via VPN), named Thomas.  This is also connected on my home network.

The Thomas PC can see Heathen on the network.

I want to login from Thomas and browse the Heathen computer.
The Thomas PC (domain network) pops up a credentials screen, asking for the account name on Heathen (non-domain).  The credential window is assuming the same domain for Thomas.

How do I specify on the credential window, the Heathen PC without a domain name?

Usual format is "\domain\account".  This isn't working for Heathen, because Heathen is not a domain network.

Comment: "HEATHEN\Administrator"is the local admin account of this computer, I agree with 1686's reply

Answer (score 0):

It's still the same format, but with the computer's name as the "domain". For example:

```
HEATHEN\Administrator
```

Comment: This is a good answer.. if you have problems with this, you can also use the IP address instead of the machine name `<ipaddr>\loginaccount` ..

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: Well, yes, but not exactly... The local SAM "domain" in non-domain computers is _specifically_ based on the computer's short name. You can see it in `whoami`. Things like IP addresses only work because non-domain computers tend to _ignore_ whatever domain was provided during login attempts (but not always -- unfortunately I can't remember whether Windows or Samba was the stricter one in that regard).

Comment: NICE!  Thanks for filling in a blank for me :)